# Problem when row reducing matrix with complex entries

Tags: matrices

I have to find a row-reduced matrix which is row-equivalent to

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc} i & -(1+i) & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2i & -1\\ \end{array}\right]$$

On one hand

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc} i & -(1+i) & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2i & -1\\ \end{array}\right] \\ \xrightarrow{R_1 \leftrightarrow R_2} \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & -2 & 1 \\ i & -(1+i) & 0 \\ 1 & 2i & -1\\ \end{array}\right]$$

$$\xrightarrow{R_2 \gets -iR_1 + R_2} \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & -1+i & -i \\ 1 & 2i & -1\\ \end{array}\right] $$

$$\xrightarrow{R_3 \gets -R_1 + R_3} \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & -1+i & -i \\ 0 & 2+2i & -2\\ \end{array}\right] $$

$$\xrightarrow{\ \frac{1}{(-1+i)}R_2} \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1/(-1-i) \\ 0 & 2+2i & -2\\ \end{array}\right] $$

$$\xrightarrow{\ R_1\gets 2R_2+R_1} \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & i \\ 0 & 1 & 1/(-1-i) \\ 0 & 2+2i & -2\\ \end{array}\right] $$

$$\xrightarrow{\ R_3\gets -(2+2i)R_2+R_3} \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & i \\ 0 & 1 & 1/(-1-i) \\ 0 & 0 & -4\\ \end{array}\right] $$

and this last matrix is equivalent to the identity matrix $I_{3x3}$.

On the other hand I reduced it with other row operations and concluded the same as [WOLFRAM ALPHA](https://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=reduced+row+form%3A+%7B%7Bi%2C+-%28i%2B1%29%2C+0%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+-2%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+2i%2C+-1%7D%7D&x=0&y=0). Which one is wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not getting what you want to describe

Comment: You want to convert it into identity matrix of 3×3?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh I end up with two different row reduced matrices, one being the identity matrix and the other one shown in the link to wolfram alpha. This means one of them must be wrong right?

Comment: Looks like a simple arithmetic error when you computed the (3,3) element in the last step. You probably forgot to include a minus sign.

Comment: @amd indeed $\frac{-(2+2i)}{-(1+i)}=2$ hence $(3,3)=0$, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in 4th step. When you are taking $(-1+i)$ common from $R_2$. Then element at 2nd row and 3rd column is wrong I think.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to multiple by $\frac{1}{-1+i}$. Already edited.

Comment: But its still wrong.

Comment: Then it becomes $\frac{i}{1-i}$.